# MSSQL Obtain the last entries added in the last 30 seconds?

Tags: sql-server

I want to obtain the last entries in the last 30 seconds from a MSSQL database.

In Mysql you do:

SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > (now() - interval 30 second)

How to do that in MSSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dateadd with a negative integer will give you the data you are asking for

[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

`SELECT
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    datetime >= DATEADD(SECOND,-30,datetime)`

Answer (score 2):

[DATEDIFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) is your solution here.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    [table] 
WHERE 
    DATEDIFF(second, [datetime], GETDATE()) < 30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GETDATE()` in combindation with `DATEADD`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetime > (DATEADD(second,-30,getdate()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [DATEADD()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

```
DATEADD(SECOND,-30,GETDATE())
```